# how does org-mode avoid re-parsing the document after every change?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to understand the internal architecture and strategy used by org-mode.

how does org-mode avoid re-parsing the document after every change?

For example, let's say I have a 2 meg org-mode file/buffer.

There is a TODO in the middle of the file.

I accidentally put a space in the middle of "TODO", so it becomes "TO DO".

After that insert, org-mode needs to remove that TODO (and possibly its children) from its internal data structures. However, from what I can tell, org wouldn't know what the change was. It would have to reparse the whole buffer and then compare the old tree with the new tree. Any agenda views would also have to update after this single keystroke.

How does org-avoid having to perform such an expensive computation for every key stroke?

Comment: `org-mode` updates with `font-lock-mode`, whereas the `*Org Agenda*` buffer is created manually each time a user creates a search or regenerates manually via a specific operation ...  If are interested, you can grep the source code for the term `font-lock` and you'll see how the definitions are set out ...  The function `org-set-font-lock-defaults` (which gets called when `org-mode` is activated) has a lot of stuff that you may find interesting ...

Comment: The `*Org Agenda*` buffer uses text-properties (instead of `font-lock`) for colors and lots of hidden information about each item.  The text-properties consist of what what may have existed when the data was gathered from the `org-mode` buffer, and additional `text-properties` are added while the data is being gathered following a search; e.g., `org-search-view`, `org-tags-view`, `org-agenda-list`.  To see more about the hidden text-properties, place your cursor on a an entry in the `org-agenda` buffer and type:  `M-x eval-expression RET (text-properties-at (point)) RET`.

Comment: thanks lawlist, I think I'm gathering that org-mode does not attempt to react to text, only org specific commands. So agenda views have to be refreshed manually.

Is that an accurate summary?

Comment: `font-lock` mode, which is used by `org-mode` (but *not* `org-agenda-mode`), refreshes whatever has changed and initially processes the buffer by hunks.  The `jit-lock` library works in conjunction with `font-lock` and there are customizations to control when certain things are processed, and there is also a timer function.  As to `font-lock`/`jit-lock`, Emacs makes decisions every command loop regarding what to do, and there are probably some org-specific triggers.  The `*Org Agenda*` buffer is fairly static/non-changing, except as to mouse-overs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, integrating comments from lawlist, and a private email from bzg, I believe I have a clearer picture.

org-mode doesn't try to maintain a consistent parallel structure represented by the text in the buffer.
You can insert or delete text anywhere in the buffer.

org-mode assumes that the user will use the org-mode commands to create, update, or archive entries.
Also, org-mode Agenda views make a similar assumption.

org-mode presents the illusion of consistency by relying on font-lock's syntax highlighting.
If the user makes a mistake, the user will have to make the correction. There are no guard rails.

One minor note, if `org-element-use-cache` is set to `t`, Org keeps an
internal representation of the element at point -- you can see line
4759 of org-element.el. This probably just makes certain commands perform better.

bzg recommended reading:

- https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html
- https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html
- https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/org-element-docstrings.html

p.s. I edited this in spacemacs org-mode